# Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: server, ssh, sftp

It is as the title says. When I try to connect to my sftp server with filezilla it says the following "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)", however before this message comes a window pops up asking me if I trust the servers host key and I say yes. Futhermore I can't find my .ssh directory anymore which contained the authorized_keys file. I am a little confused. Have anyone of you guys any tips or ideas to solve this issue?

Thanks on beforehand.

Comment: Well if you have configured SSH to look in `~/.ssh` for the `authorized_keys` file, and it does not exist, you will need to recreate it and re-copy your public key there (or generate a new keypair)

Comment: since I don't know where the keys, I am thinking of generating a new pair of keys but if the keys but if the keys are left somwhere on the server, will they be over written?

Answer (score 1):

Your server is configured to deny anything else than public key-based authentication.

If you have lost your `.ssh` (and hence, your RSA, DSA, .... key pair), then you can no longer login to your remote system.

Depending on who's hosting this remote system, you may be able to use some KVM over IP, VNC console, ... reboot the server on some liveCD, ... Point is: if you can't find a copy of your SSH key pair, then you'll have to enable password-based authentication somehow.

Comment: I will propably make a new pair of keys since I want key-based authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Please do not laugh, but make sure that you have not renamed that user's home directory as defined in `/etc/passwd`. I had long ago and since forgotten about it (I SSH with another account and `sudo su` over). Finding my error was hours long, but changing the folder name and rebooting was less than 60 seconds.    
`username:x:1007:1007::/var/www/new_folder:/bin/bash`